# Finding X number of most frequent Nouns in part-of-speech (PoS) column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, part-of-speech

I have a PoS column that has labelled words as nouns, adjectives or verbs. My current code extracts all the noun words and stores them in a new column of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

data = {'comments':['Daniel is really cool', 'Daniel is the most amazing host!', 'Daniel is highly recommended']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize

df['tokenized_text'] = df['comments'].apply(word_tokenize) 
    
df['tagged'] = df['tokenized_text'].apply(pos_tag)
```

```
def get_vocab(df):   
    
    nouns = []
    
    for (word, pos) in df:
        if pos.startswith("NN"):
            nouns.append(word)
    
    return nouns

df["nouns"] = df["tagged"].apply(get_vocab)
```

However, I'd like to store all the noun words in a list instead of the dataframe and only include the top 100 frequent noun words. How would I go about this? My desired list would look like this:

```
['Daniel', 'is']
```

As this is a small example I'd only have those two, but in my actual dataset I would have thousands of repeated nouns and so I'd like to only store the top 100 most common nouns.

Comment: Is this pandas?

Comment: Yes it's pandas

Comment: You should consider writing a [mcve] so that we exactly know what's in the `tagged` column.

Comment: You have already stored the nouns in `noun` list. Now do you want to count the frequent words in it? Also please add what your dataframe looks like and what is the output that you want.

Comment: I've just added an example. I assume I would want to count the frequent words in it but only store the top X most frequent words.

Comment: how about `list(pd.Series([e for sl in list(df["nouns"]) for e in sl]).value_counts(sort=True).index[:100])` ? mix of list comprehension and value_counts?